# Plyer TTS not working after packaging with pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, pyinstaller

I've looked everywhere for a hint about what is wrong, but so far I haven't been able to uncover any information. I just made a simple app that imported tts from plyer to say a small sentence after a button was clicked. It works perfectly when I run it until I package the files using pyinstaller. After using pyinstaller, I get

```
   File "site-packages/plyer/facades/tts.py", line 11, in speak
   File "site-packages/plyer/facades/tts.py", line 16, in _speak
 NotImplementedError
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. I'm using python 3.5 on OS X.

Comment: I'd check how plyer achieves the TTS. If it's calling a library, it's possible that it would fail this way if your package doesn't include that library.

Comment: I copied and pasted the plyer folder into the application, and this seemed to have fixed the problem. Is there a way tell pyinstaller to include it? It automatically included other packages for my other apps such as openpyxl.

Comment: @AccPy there is something like `hiddenimports` or something in a similar way in PyInstaller's spec, that should include packages you list there explicitly.